# How can I fix code get number phone to run on my real device?

Tags: android, phone-number, telephony

I coded the project(minSDKVersion: 15) to get number phone and When I run on the AVD of android studio(API 26), it runs ok. But when I run on my real device(android version: 4.4.2), I click button "Click me" then it crushed and the notice is "Unfortunately, My Application has stopped". I don't know that my device is not suitable version or what wrong?
My code:

```
Button btnStart;
TextView varText;
String info;
String strPhoneType = "";
static final int PERMISSION_READ_STATE = 123;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void Start(View view) {
    int permissionClick = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    if (permissionClick == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        MyTelephonyManager();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, PERMISSION_READ_STATE);
    }
}
```

Override method to request permission read number phone:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode){
        case PERMISSION_READ_STATE:
        {
            if(grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                MyTelephonyManager();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You don't have required permisson to make the Action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Method to get information of phone, include phone number:

```
private void MyTelephonyManager(){
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int phoneType = manager.getPhoneType();
    switch (phoneType){
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA):
            strPhoneType = "CDMA";
            break;
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM):
            strPhoneType = "GSM";
            break;
        case (TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE):
            strPhoneType = "None";
            break;
    }

    boolean isRoaming = manager.isNetworkRoaming();
    String PhoneType = strPhoneType;
    String IMEINumber = manager.getImei();
    String subcriberID = manager.getSubscriberId();
    String simSerialNumber = manager.getSimSerialNumber();
    String networkCountryISO = manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
    String simCountryISO = manager.getSimCountryIso();
    String softwareVersion = manager.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();
    String voiceMailNumber = manager.getVoiceMailNumber();

    info = "Phone details: \n";
    info += "\n Phone Network type: " + PhoneType;
    info += "\n IMEINumber: " + IMEINumber;
    info += "\n subcriberID: " + subcriberID;
    info += "\n simSerialNumber: " + simSerialNumber;
    info += "\n networkCountryISO: " + networkCountryISO;
    info += "\n simCountryISO: " + simCountryISO;
    info += "\n softwareVersion: " + softwareVersion;
    info += "\n voiceMailNumber: " + voiceMailNumber;
    info += "\n isRoaming: " + isRoaming;

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBtnStart);
    varText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idTxtView);
    varText.setText(info);
}
```

Comment: First thing that came to my mind after looking at **MyTelephonyManager();** was; where is *new*!!! That's why its good to use standard Java naming convention.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean - "where is new!!!" ???